# Auth0 - get user logins to particular client

Tags: auth0

Is there a way to retrieve Auth0 logins to a particular client? I have a common set of users across 2 different clients (2 different applications) and would like to get at the login data separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use the management API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Logs/get_logs) to retrieve the logs by client ID, like so:

`curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" https://your-tenant.auth0.com/api/v2/logs?q=client_id%3Aexample-client-id`

Here are some doc links on getting started with the Auth0 Management v2 API, including how to get a Bearer token:

- [Management v2. docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2)
- [Management v2. tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/tokens)